# Style not applying correctly to background image

Tags: css

I am a student and I'm having an issue with one of the video tutorials regarding using a background image.  I followed the code exactly as is in the video but it's not producing the same results.  It just keeps showing the image tiled throughout the whole web-page.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
<style type="text/css">
   body {
      background-image:url(goku.jpg);
      background-repeat:no-repeat;
      background-attachment: 50% 60px;
   }    
</style>
```

Comment: I don't know why it's not showing but I included the style sheet of <style type="text/css"> my code from original post </style>  to my code in HTML.  Sorry if its not showing in the question above.

Comment: Hello @bluemug, what do you want to achieve with the background? Do you want it to display on the whole page or just a part of it?

Comment: the video tutorial I was following the guy was moving a picture of his face around the web page.  Specifically, he placed the image in the middle of the web page.  Have a link to the video which is youtu.be/jWn1nWIFbV0.

Answer (score 2):

Your `background-attachment` value is invalid, and you should add a `background-size`setting. In the snippet below I used `cover` to cover the whole screen, but you can also use other sizes. But then you should also add `background-position`

EDIT after comment: Well then just change to `background-position: 50% 50%;`. The image - if you don't use `background-size` will be displayed at its original size, and with that setting, be centered horizontally and vertically. If you don't like the vertical centering, change the second value to whatever you like, also in pixels, if you want.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-image: url(https://placehold.it./240x180/fb4);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div>Test</div>
```

Comment: Johannes, thank you for answering.  The effect was not what I intended.  The video tutorial I was following aligned the image in the middle of the web page among other things that were not taking effect when I tried it.  The video was https://youtu.be/jWn1nWIFbV0.